# How use mongoDb with cordova app ( mongodb with js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, cordova

I want to create cross-platform app with Cordova  and PhoneGap.

So I need online database for it, But MYSQL can't run with Js in mobiles.
But I want to online database for that app, and **MongoDb** is best for that.

But can't find how to get data to HTML page from MongoDb.

Can any one help me.......

Comment: This is kind of a broad question. Have you checked out any online tutorials or how-to's?

Comment: Thank you sir, Yes i was checked, but i coudn't find any kind of usual answer.

Comment: Try this out: https://codeburst.io/hitchhikers-guide-to-back-end-development-with-examples-3f97c70e0073

Answer (score 1):

sometimes you'll need to run separate tutorials to gain a proper understanding of how the different technologies work with each other.  Later you will be able to combine them from your dev ops understanding that you have gained.

Here is something I found which may be helpful for you.  This is in three parts but it looks like it covers what you are asking about.

http://martinmicunda.com/2015/04/10/build-ionic-photo-gallery-app-I/

Answer (score 1):

If you mean you need a local database with cordova that is not SQLlite for persistence and you want something that looks like mongodb instead, check out [**mongogx**](https://github.com/globules-io/mongogx)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you want a remote database or a local one. If you want local mongoDB storage in Cordova, I've written a plugin that provides just that. It is still very limited but gives you the basis CRUD operations on a local database

The git repository can be found [here](https://github.com/mikakrooswijk/cordova-mongodb-storage)